# Cloning a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I am printing a `JFrame`. Before doing so, I hide the menu bar and set the `JFrame` to undecorated.  This works just fine but the visible `JFrame` changes to reflect the removed controls which I must later restore.

I would like to clone the `JFrame`, do the modifications to that and print from the clone.

Is there a way to clone a `JFrame` so I can modify it for printing?

I tried cloning but that failed with a very non-informative

```
CloneNotSupportedException exception.
```

When I try to clone, variable remains null and I get an exception.  The exception is `PlotterPkg.MainJFrame`, the name of my outermost `JFrame` and my package name.

```
JFrame jjj = null;
try
{
    jjj = (JFrame) this.clone();
}
catch (CloneNotSupportedException ex)
{                 
    java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger
       (MainJFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

Comment: Wh not just create a new instance of the frame?

Comment: You might be able to use a copy constructor to construct an instance of the `JFrame`.  For more help post [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your suggestion.  However, I came up with another solution.

I created another JPanel, moved all the controls onto the new underlying panel and printed that panel.  It worked like a charm.

Comment: Don't do any of the things you were trying to do. Simply print the content pane (`JFrame.getContentPane()`) of the original frame.